# How to expand input to take remaining room in a div

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a dropdown that drops down a custom panel (div) instead of a list of options. That panel is irrelevant because it is not tied to the layout I am asking about. For the basic drop-down look I have the following:

```
<style>
    .folder-selection {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .dropdown-button {
        float: right;
    }
</style>

    <div id=container>
        <input type="text" class="folder-selection" />
        <button type="button" class="dropdown-button">...</button>
    </div>
```

Now I know the float and width 100% are not right, but I have a container div, with an input on the left and a button on the right. The button must remain fixed to the right of the input. If the container is narrow, the input must be narrow, and vice versa, but I want to achieve this without knowing at design time the width of the container.

The container should fit into any width and the input's width should adjust accordingly. Just like a normal `select` element, where the text portion always fills all the space not taken by the dropdown icon/button at its right.

Comment: I've some trouble understanding your question fully, but usually you can set a absolutely positioned drop-down (no matter if list or div) in a relatively positioned parent.

Comment: Just give the button a fixed width say, `200px`, and the input the rest of the width: `calc(100% - 200px)` give or take a few pixels for the whitespace.

Comment: Can you post an illustration of what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: @Aer0 I don't want a ready-made dropdown, I want to make one.

Comment: @Terry I want a custom dropdown, simple. A textbox and button, with my own div that drops down. Whatever the width of the textbox, the button must always be at its right.

Comment: Is the question about positioning the panel or "(having) the input fill the remaining space"? In the former case, please add some markup for the panel (edit: and explain what you want to achieve: autocomplete maybe?) and in the latter case please clarify your question

Comment: Examples of [Toggle](https://inclusive-components.design/tooltips-toggletips/#inclusivetoggletips) (it opens a dropdown in my vocabulary) and [autocomplete](https://github.com/nico3333fr/jquery-accessible-autocomplete-list-aria)

Comment: @FelipeAls I am not asking about toggling nor about autocomplete.

Comment: Then what is your question about? Is it about positioning the panel (appears nowhere in your code) or about relative horizontal widths of input and button (unrelated to the title of your question) or something else (some picture of expected result please)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below example will help you. Let me know, if you don't want fixed width icon in right so I'll update this code accordingly.

```css
#container {
 position: relative;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 5px 40px 5px 5px;
 margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.folder-selection {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 5px;
 border: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 height: 30px;
}
.dropdown-button {
 position: absolute;
 top: 5px;
 right: 5px;
 height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
 <input type="text" class="folder-selection" />
 <button type="button" class="dropdown-button">...</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, and neater than the first correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: Why does the selector for `container` have to be an id and not a class? I'm trying to write a reusable View Component, so I would rather not use any IDs, as who knows what other IDs there will be wherever it is used.

Comment: Ah, I see it's only if you use the single word `container`. If I change it to a more local and unknown name I can use a class instead. E.g. `.folder-selector` instead of `#container` seems to work fine.

Comment: You can change id to any class name. May I ask that why you make it unaccepted first time?

Comment: I didn't like the use of an `id` selector, but once I worked around that and made it a `class` selector, your solution with mod was perfect and I accepted it for final.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.dropdown-button {
    width: 16px;  /*Set width of button*/
}

.folder-selection {
    width: calc(100% - 16px); /*div's width minus button's width*/
}
</style>

<div id=container>
    <input type="text" class="folder-selection" /><!-- this comment is to remove white space between the two elements
--><button type="button" class="dropdown-button">...</button>
</div>
```

You don't really have to set the width of the button as long as you know its width on runtime.

Comment: I get an input the full width of the screen, and a button below it at extreme left. It looks like that `calc` in the style isn't working. I am using this in an ASP.NET Core MVC project, with the standard `_Layout.cshtml` as my 'master' page.

Comment: 1. What browser are you using? 2. Did you substract the exact width of the button? If not, the button will go bottom left as you said. 3. Did you remove the white space? (refer to the html comment above). 

Try adjusting to `calc(80% - 16px)` to find out if the problem is in `calc` or in something else.

Comment: 1) Chrome, 2) yes, 3)no. It's working now anyway, but I'll still try and make this version work because `calc` is new to me and I want to see it working.

Comment: I apologize. When I tried your code again, it seemed to work fine. Yet why the `container` id? I much prefer working nearly only with classes. This is an academic question, I see it affects nothing, but how many of the same id are there wherever my component is used.

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you're saying. I just copied your code above and modified it to your needs.

Answer (score -1):

This code will help you to position your elements as you expected.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dropdown-container {
  width: 500px;
  display: table;
  background: orange;
}

.dropdown-container .input-container {
  display: table-cell;
}

.dropdown-container .input-container input {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.dropdown-container .button-container {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 150px;
}

.dropdown-container .button-container button {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-container">
  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" class="folder-selection" />
  </div>
  <div class="button-container">
    <button type="button" class="dropdown-button">Drop</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is this answer voted down? It seems to answer my question.

Comment: Thank you. I gave you a point, but the accepted answer is neater. Thanks.